# How to change checkbox follow JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, checkbox

I want to change checkbox follow JSON string . But i don't know how do it .
This is me JSON string, "1" is mean checked and "0" is mean unchecked

```
[{"Group_Product":"G04","Orange":1,"Banana":0,"Apple":1,"Candy":0,"Food":1}]
```

And html code.

```html
<table id=table_product>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Orange" name="check[]" />Orange</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Banana" name="check[]" />Banana</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Apple" name="check[]" />Apple</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Candy" name="check[]" />Candy</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Food" name="check[]" />Food</td></tr>   
</table>
```

Ok , i use this ways.I'll get name and value in Object JSON, then compare with id of checkbox and checked it.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                            for (var item in obj[0]) {
                                if (item.valueOf > 0) {
                                    document.getElementById(item).checked = true;
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                    }
```

If you have a idea or solution, share with me.

Comment: Json includes booleans - use `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`

Comment: the main issue here is to change the checkbox under JSON, JSON string longer I can change according to 1 and 0 or true and false.I think it's just the comparison = 1 or = "true" is checked. It is not very important

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: No , them is not same , different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an Id to your checkboxes...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="chkApple"  name="check[]" />Apple
```

Then check them as follows:

```
success: function (data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
    $("#chkApple").prop('checked', obj[0].Apple > 0);
}
```

or better yet, change your Json to use booleans not integers and you get...

```
    $("#chkApple").prop('checked', obj[0].Apple);
```

Note that we're using `obj[0]` because your Json is a currently list with a single object. Did you intend that?

If not, remove the `[]` from the json...

```
{"Group_Product":"G04","Orange":true,"Banana":false,"Apple":true,"Candy":false,"Food":true}
```

and then it becomes

```
    $("#chkApple").prop('checked', obj.Apple);
```

To answer your question in comments...

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
for (var item in obj[0]) {
    document.getElementById(item).checked = obj[0][item] > 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added id to my checkbox , same name of JSON object `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="Orange"  name="check[]" />Orange` . And i don't know can i use this ways `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                            for (var i = 0; i < obj.properties; i++) {
                                $('"#' + obj.properties[i].name + '"').prop('checked', obj.properties[i].value > 0);
                            }`

Comment: Is this because the list of properties is dynamic? The approach you're taking seems perfectly valid but I'd need to see an example page and/or look in the debugged to work out why it might not be working. Be aware this approach is slightly fragile as you're hoping you won't have any Ids clash (what if I had another element with Id `Orange` or your Json had a field called `body` - either would break.). Consider pre-pending a constant string to the id

Comment: Well, @basic, please see update my question . List checkbox in a table , and i'll get name `Apple,Banana,Candy,...` and set checkbox is `true` . But I'm missing here is finding the value 1 or 0 to each item . Do you have idea ?

Comment: See my edit which should make it clear. Be aware that's you're using tables wrong in your question. You need to specify rows and columns`<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>`

Comment: Dear @basic , so hurry too, so I lack `<tr> <td> ... </ td> </ tr>`. Thank you for reminding . I have updated code . I use answer of you and get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null` , because not checkbox with id `Group_Product` and value of it is `G04` .I thinking about this.

Comment: No worries. Have I answered your question? Working Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j8t754em/

Comment: I use answer of you and get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null` , because not checkbox with id `Group_Product` and value of it is `G04` .I thinking about this.

Comment: See the jsfiddle in my previous comment. I'm checking for that. It's worth noting that if you used the jQuery `$('#Id')` syntax, you wouldn't need that check, but using the non-jQuery `document.getElementById` returns `null` if the id doesn't exist

Comment: Well , it's work ,I have seen,  You should update answer . thank you so much